# how to get all possible results in list that equal or smaller than 2 but equal or greater than 1?

Tags: python

For example:
To find all possible lists with length=3, and all elements are equal or smaller than 2 but equal or greater than 1. (you can use numpy)

```
input: len = 3, m = 1, n=2
output:[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,1],[2,1,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

(it's a little bit like np.random.randint, but we hope to get all results)
[image]

Comment: Please share what *you* have tried

Comment: smaller than 2, greater than 1? Give me a scenario where that is True.

Comment: hi, all, I've added a example of numpy.random.randint

Comment: Itertools might have something useful, such as permutations.

Comment: @FishballNooodles - it says `<= 2 and >= 1` which is a wierd way of saying it needs to be 1 or 2

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra hi, i added an example

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way but you could do this:

```
from itertools import permutations

s = [list(t) for t in {p for p in permutations([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 3)}]

print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work if m and n changes, for instance, m=1, n=10. In this complex case, how to input the list into the permutations? more loops may be needed. is there any simple way to get all results? like scipy or numpy?

Comment: @dlwu When you change your question, not all answers will necessarily work for you